# Droplet with a progress bar?

Tags: terminal, applescript, automation, encoding

First of all, apologies for my ignorance on the subject. All of this ffmpeg and automation is new for me and sometimes I cannot see even evident things.

I am learning command lines to encode videos (I use FFMPEG to change settings of the video, watermark, all this sort of things to improve my workflow)

Now I am trying to transform those command lines in to Applescript droplets apps to make life easier. Last night I managed to turn my first one in an Applescript app droplet but I am missing the progress which I can see when I use the command shell.

I.E.

I can see frames per second, how much inside de video ... this sort of info

[image: progress I can see if using the script on terminal window]

I would like to know if there is a way to modify / add something on this script to see similar progress, either tell terminal to open while executing the script or a detailed progress bar pop up.

This is the scrip I am currently starting with

```
for f in "$@"
do

/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/Library/Fonts/Tahoma.ttf: text='Central Text':\ x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h-line_h)/2: fontsize=100: fontcolor=white@0.2" -s 720x406 -c:v libx264 -b:v 1400k -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:a 192k "${f%.*}_watermarked.mov"
done
```

Comment: And what do you have in your droplet

Comment: Also have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppleScript/RN-AppleScript/RN-10_10/RN-10_10.html

Comment: @markhunte , The droplet is the code pasted above. I am sorry, I think didn't understand your question.

Comment: Just thought you could show the droplet code including the Applescript. I do not think using native Applescript at least you will get this type of verbose feed back to use in a progress bar. You could iterate each file as it changes to the next one in the bath.

Comment: @markhunte I would assume the droplet code is just a wrapper script that executes the shell script shown above.

Comment: @markhunte in that case is there a way to add on the script something telling to open terminal and execute the action? I wound't mind to have the terminal window open for executing the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just have terminal open and run you can get an idea from below.

It is not very neat but works of sorts..

example:

```
on open myFiles
        set bigList to {}
        repeat with i from 1 to number of items in myFiles
            set this_item to item i of myFiles
            copy (quoted form of POSIX path of this_item) & space to end of bigList
        end repeat
     tell application "Terminal"


            do script ("for f in  " & items of bigList as string) & "
    do

    echo  \"$f\"

    done"

        end tell
end open
```